# Import raster to postgis, raster2pgsql ERROR

Tags: postgresql, postgis, raster

I execute in cmd:

```
raster2pgsql -s 4326 -I -C -M C:\Users\alber\Desktop\acambarop1.tif -F -t 11887x14513 public.acambaro | psql -d cartos -U postgres -p 5432
```

and the write the password, next message

```
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE

ERROR:  memoria agotada
DETALLE:  No se puede agrandar el bufer de cadena que ya tiene 0 bytes en 1380128476 bytes adicionales.
ERROR:  transaccion abortada, las ordenes seran ignoradas hasta el fin de bloque de transaccion
ERROR:  transaccion abortada, las ordenes seran ignoradas hasta el fin de bloque de transaccion
ERROR:  transaccion abortada, las ordenes seran ignoradas hasta el fin de bloque de transaccion
ROLLBACK
ERROR:  no existe la relacion «public.acambaro»
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong, I dont understand the memory error...

Help

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

Add the parameter `-c` to your `raster2pgsql` command and it will create a table for you, so that you can avoid the error:

> ERROR:  no existe la relacion «public.acambaro»

Alternatively you can use `-d` to drop an existing table and creating a new one or `-p` to append the data into an existing table.

See [`raster2pgsql documentation`](https://postgis.net/docs/using_raster_dataman.html#RT_Raster_Loader):

> - -c Create new table and populate it with raster(s), this is the default mode
> - -a Append raster(s) to an existing table.
> - -d Drop table, create new one and populate it with raster(s)
> - -p Prepare mode, only create the table.

Considering that my Spanish skills aren't betraying me, the other error says your memory is exhausted - although a 1.38GB file isn't that big. I would first try to import a smaller file to make sure that the problem isn't at the `raster2pgsql` syntax.

> ERROR:  memoria agotada 
>   DETALLE:  No se puede agrandar el bufer de
>   cadena que ya tiene 0 bytes en 1380128476 bytes adicionales.

Comment: Hi I resolve it, I would post my answer thank you for the feedback

Comment: @AlbertoAaronPerez consider accepting one of the answer, so that other users can profit from it.

Answer (score 0):

In GIS.Stackexcange I found the answer

link... [ANSWER](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254328/psql-import-raster-out-of-memory?newreg=7a5155b198f248609b5c2162c76a474a)

I must `set client_encoding 'WIN1252'`

No UTF8